# ASP.NET - SmtpClient.Send never catches exception

Tags: asp.net, email, exception, smtpclient

So i have a ASP.NET application with an account creation screen where the user inserts his data to create an account. Among other things, it asks for the user's email address which is essential in order to receive the password. In order to validate the inserted email address, i'm using a regex to check if the format is acceptable. However, the user can still write a random email that doesn't exist (ex: "sfsag@asfa.sfa.saf"). And the "Send" method from SmtpClient will send to it whether the email actually exists or not. I tried to catch the exception (SmtpException, SmtpFailedRecipientsException and normal Exception) to avoid these situations but the SmtpClient ignores it and sends the email regardless if the email address is actually valid or not.

Here's the code in question by the way:

```
public static bool MailPassword(String email, String pwd)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress("admin@candidaturas.com")
            };

            msg.To.Add(email);
            msg.Subject = "Password de Acesso";
            msg.Body = "A password de acesso para a sua conta é a seguinte: " + pwd;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = Constants.Host,
                Port = Constants.Port
            };

            System.Net.NetworkCredential ntwd = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = Constants.Email,
                Password = Constants.Password
            };

            smt.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smt.Credentials = ntwd;
            smt.EnableSsl = true;
            smt.Send(msg);

            return true;
        }
        catch(SmtpFailedRecipientsException smtpe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", smtpe.StatusCode);
            return false;
        }
        catch (SmtpException smtpe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", smtpe.StatusCode);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}", e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sending a password in this email?

Comment: If the smtpclient can send to your server, it's success, even if it fails out on the internet.

Comment: Only the *server* knows whether an email exists or not, and that only after trying to send an email.The exceptions are raised because the *server* sends an error response. Bad domains may get a quick error response. Bad addresses may wait for hours before a response is received by the target domains sender.

Comment: BTW you *can't* use a regex to validate emails. The format is too complex and can easily contain what you'd consider special characters. Even if you validate the address with a regex you just can't know if `someUserName123_45` exists in the `somedomain.somewhere.tv`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you're saying there's no way to check if the email exists or not?

Comment: @brupal89 I suspect you should rethink what you are trying to do. First of all, you *can't* send the password. It's a basic security (and legal) requirement. Passwords get salted and hashed, so it's impossible to recover them. That's how ASP.NET's authentication mechanism works btw. You can only send *reset links*, to the user's registered address. If that's wrong, tough luck for them but you won't compromise your system